# Updating a framework in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode6

I am developing a framework.. I managed to build a 1.0 version but Now I have added a new class to the framework but this class is not visible to everything else it seems.. What are the steps to "recompile" or fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using Swift or Objective C or both? Do you get any explicit error messages?

Comment: I am using Swift.. It says Use of undecladed type when I try to use it..

Answer (score 0):

This could be down to lots of things, but I was in a similar situation yesterday and the cause was my failure to put all the relevant files in the *Compile Sources* table (found by  selecting your framework in the *Targets* browser, and navigating to the *Build Phases* section):

[image]

---

If you're using Swift, and you're trying to access the classes in your framework from some other target/framework, you also need to make sure you've marked the classes you're trying to access as `public` (they're `internal` by default).

```
// Mark class as public so it's available to other frameworks
public class Logger {

    // Can only access this from this file
    private var log: [LogEntry] = [] 

    // Only classes in this framework can access this
    var liveLog: LogEntryPriority? = .Info // Can only get at this

    // Can access this from anywhere
    public func getReady(logLevel: LogEntryPriority, errorsAreFatal: Bool) {
        log = []
        liveLog = logLevel
        self.errorsAreFatal = errorsAreFatal
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope.. it was empty before but the other old classes still work.. should be something else.. I even tried recreating the framework and dragged all the classes inside all over but that particular class doesn't seem to be recognized